# Difference between Sampajanna and Vipassana

Tags: theravada, vipassana, meditation

If Sampajanna is clear comprehension and Vipassana is clearly seeing how or are they distinguishable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sampajanna* is a prerequisite for right concentration. *Vipassana* is a result of right concentration.

Mindfulness > *sampajanna* > concentration > *vipassana* > liberation > nibbana

*Sampajanna* is a product of active volition & mindfulness; what is called '*wise or careful attention' (yoni­so­ma­nasikāro)*; as described in AN 10.61:

> *Mindfulness and clear comprehension, too, I say, have a nutriment; they are not without nutriment. And what is the nutriment for mindfulness and clear comprehension? It should be said: careful attention (yoni­so­ma­nasikāro). [AN 10.61](https://suttacentral.net/en/an10.61)*

Vipassana is the *automatic* seeing of ultimate truth that occurs when the mind is clear & concentrated, as described in [AN 11.2](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.002.than.html).

> *For a person whose mind is concentrated, there is no need for an act of will, 'May I know & see things as they actually are.' It is in the nature of things that a person whose mind is concentrated knows & sees things as they actually are. [AN 11.2](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.002.than.html)*

*Sampajanna* (*applied wisdom*) is the preliminary wisdom that mindfulness (remembering; recollection) brings to mind to establish meditation. Again, to quote AN 10.61:

> *The four establishments of mindfulness, too, I say, have a nutriment; they are not without nutriment. And what is the nutriment for the four establishments of mindfulness? It should be said: ... mindfulness and clear comprehension. [AN 10.61](https://suttacentral.net/en/an10.61)*

For example, when meditation is established, *sampajanna* applies the types of wisdoms listed below, when required:

1. observing breathing brings peace therefore it is beneficial to observe the breathing
2. craving & attachment cause suffering & disturbances therefore I should meditate without craving & attachment
3. this hindrance harms myself & harms another therefore it should be abandoned

Bhikkhu Buddhadasa has explained 'sampajanna' & 'vipassana' below:

> *sampajanna, wisdom-in-action, ready comprehension, clear comprehension: the specific application of  panna as required in a
> given situation.*
>
> *vipassana, insight: literally, "clear seeing," to see clearly, distinctly, directly into the true nature of  things, into
> aniccam-dukkham-anatta. Vipassana is popularly used for mental
> development practiced for the sake of true insight. In such cases, the
> physical posture, theory, and method of such practices must not be
> confused with true realization of impermanence, unsatisfactori­ness,
> and not-self. Vipassana cannot be taught.*
>
> *SAMPAJAÑÑA*
>
> ***Sampajanna** is wisdom as it meets up with and immediately confronts a problem, as it deals with and wipes
> out that problem -- this is wisdom-in-action. It is only that wisdom
> specifically related and applied to a particular situation or event.
> The word "**wisdom**" (**paññä**) encompasses many
> meanings and understandings, we can't even begin to estimate its
> content. However, the word "**sampajanna**" is far more limited in its
> meaning. It is exactly that wisdom directly needed for the problem
> that confronts us. Active wisdom isn't general, it is a matter of
> particulars.*
>
> *We can compare **wisdom** (**paññä**) with the medicine chest in our house. In it we store a wide variety of drugs, pills, capsules, ointments, powders,
> and syrups for possible use. When we're actually sick, we must choose
> from among the many the one drug which will be effective in treating
> our ailment. We can't take them all; we take just what is needed to
> cure our illness here and now. The same is true for wisdom. Understand
> that there's an incredible amount of what we call paññä,
> but that we only apply a little bit at a time. We apply just that
> portion which can take care of the immediate situation. Know how to
> use the Dhamma, the paññä, which is exactly relevant to our situation
> and problem. The Dhamma or wisdom which controls that situation and
> problem is what we call "sampajanna."*
>
> [*The Scientific Cure of Spiritual Disease*](http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Natural_Cure_for_Spiritual_Disease2.htm)

Answer (score -1):

In short [Sati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(Buddhism)) with [Sampajanna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampaja%C3%B1%C3%B1a) is Samma Sati which is [Vipassana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipassan%C4%81).

> From this it becomes evident that according to the Buddha, whenever there is sammasati or satipatthana, it is always with sampajanna. That means it is with panna (wisdom). Otherwise it is mere sati, which is mere remembrance or awareness.

Source: [Sampajanna-the Constant Thorough Understanding of Impermanence](http://www.vridhamma.org/Sampajanna-the-Thorough-Understanding) by VRI

Comment: Sati is not vipassana, seriously. sammasati, in maggasacca, is adhicittasikkha, in tisikkha.

Comment: Sati + Sampajanna = Vipassana

Comment: So, sati+sampajanna are sila and samadhi, too.

Comment: This is Right Mindfulness which comes under Samadhi

Comment: Seriously. Sati and sampajañña always appear in the third jhāna context, too. Sati-Sampajañña of Right Mindfulness in 3th jhāna is samatha.  It is not just vipassanā. Sati-Sampajañña is sīla and samatha, too. The example "pītiyā ca virāgā upekkhako ca vihāsiṃ sato ca sampajāno, sukhañca kāyena paṭisaṃvedesiṃ". You must memorize tipitaka, to learn it. You can not just read it to understand tipitaka.

Answer (score -1):

In sampajaññaṃ 4 --asammohasampajañña is vipassana.

sampajaññaṃ 4 = clear comprehension; clarity of consciousness; awareness

1. sātthakasampajaññaṃ - clear comprehension of purpose.
2. sappāyasampajaññaṃ - clear comprehension of suitability.
3. gocarasampajaññaṃ - clear comprehension of the domain in physical
   and mind.
4. **asammohasampajañña - clear comprehension of non-delusion, or of reality.**

see: http://84000.org/tipitaka/dic/d_item.php?i=189

Comment: asammohasampajañña  is not vipassana. asammohasampajañña is viewing the mind during meditation and knowing clearly the mind is not meditating with self-view & other delusions. kind regards

Comment: @Dhammadhatu Vipassanā in bhaṅgañaṇa-uddesa (k.n.paṭisam.) refer to balava-vipassanā. So the lower ñāṇa also vipassanā, too. Because dhammaṭṭhitiñāṇa, in paṭisambhidāmagga, contemplate about paṭiccasamuppāda, too.

Comment: Sampajañña, in the third of 4 samādhibhāvanā in saṅgītisutta also is 
 taught "See vatthu of vedanā to make it apparent for sampajañña". This method also is appear in visuddhimagga diṭṭhivisuddhiniddesa (method to do when the nāma are not appear to ñāṇa). See the sutta context and it's commentary for more detail.